# Plot three lists using plot_trisurf but got IndexError

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, 3d

I want to plot two surface plots from four lists, which are all independent from each other.

I tried this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d as Axes3D

X = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
Y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]  
Z1 = [0.735, 0.735, 0.735, 0.735, 0.735, 0.735, 0.735, 0.735, 0.735, 0.735] # the elements here happens to be the same, but could be different
Z2 = [0.8623, 0.9461, 0.9341, 0.976, 0.982, 0.976, 0.976, 0.976, 0.976, 0.976]
X = np.array(X)
Y = np.array(Y)
Z1 = np.array(Z1)
Z2 = np.array(Z2)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(X,Y)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121,projection='3d')
surf1 = ax1.plot_trisurf(X.flatten(),Y.flatten(),Z1.flatten(),cmap = cm.jet, antialiased=True)        
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122,projection='3d')
surf2 = ax2.plot_trisurf(X.flatten(),Y.flatten(),Z2.flatten(),cmap = cm.jet, antialiased=True)
```

However, an IndexError pops out saying that "index 40 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 10".

Given that all lists have length 10, I thought the "index 40" may be due to `meshgrid`, but when I deleted that line, there is another error in "qhull Delauney triangulation calculation".

From my search, it seemed like a majority of 3d plots are function-based, i.e. z=f(x,y). I am not sure if the errors here are because such a relationship does not exist in my case.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Think about the shapes of your arrays. After using `meshgrid`, `X` and `Y` have shapes of `(10, 10)`, but `Z1` and `Z2` are still shape (10). You need a value of Z for every point in the (X, Y) grid

Answer (score 0):

Meshgrid changes the shape of X,Y:

```
>>> X, Y = np.meshgrid(X,Y)
>>> X.shape, Y.shape
(10,10) (10,10)
```

But Z1 and Z2 still have the shapes `(10,)`. So to provide the same dimensionality along all axes, mesh Z1 and Z2:

```
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X,Y)
Z1,Z2 = np.meshgrid(Z1, Z2)
```

And you will get the correct plot:

[image]